# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on MYSQLcommand

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

Once in every few hundred times I get an error on the life site 'bout losing the object.
I've been checking and testing and testing but have not got a clue what's goin' wrong.
Anyone some bright idea?

***The code is:***

```
Dim MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQLC, MySqlConnect)
Try
   Tries = 5
   lg &= " Co("
   Do
       Try : MySqlCommand.Connection.Open()
       Catch ex As Exception
          lg &= " " & ex.Message 
          Wait(0.5) 
       End Try
       If (MySqlCommand.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open) Then Tries -= 1 
   Loop While Tries > 0 And MySqlCommand.Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open
   lg &= ")"
Catch ex As Exception
   lg &= ex.message
End Try

lg &= " " & LCase(Left(SQLC, 5)) & "(Mc"

Try
    lg &= "En" : Dim ret = MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    lg = ""
Catch ex As Exception
   lg &= ":" & ex.message  
End Try

if lg<>"" then  Response.write(lg)
```

***The Output is:***

Co() updat(McEn:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a .net logging framework, like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). Log what is happening on your page.

In my experience, logging is the best way to catch intermittent bugs.